# Hooking Delphi TReader.OnFindComponentClass

Tags: delphi, vcl, tlabel

How can one make use of [`TReader.OnFindComponentClass`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TReader.OnFindComponentClass)? `TReader` creation is hard-coded in `TStream.ReadComponent`. I do not see a place, where one can hook the event.

`TStream.ReadComponent` is not virtual. And even if it were, if one had to derive `TStream`, one can as well derive `TReader` directly and the `OnFindComponentClass` won't be of much use. I believe that must be some easy way to hook the event, otherwise the even would not make must sense. But I cannot identify it.

The reason I'm asking is the answer by @DavidHeffernan to:
[TLabel displays accelerator keys even when the UI state says not to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6912424/850848#6914391).

> I make sure that I always create `TUIStateAwareLabel` rather than `TLabel` **by hooking the form streaming mechanism with `TReader.OnFindComponentClass`**.