# Delphi: Changing the Button Color using a Class Helper

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I need to change the visual style of my delphi form controls inorder to show them from a .Net environment. To do this, I need to change the colors of delphi controls to blue ($00FCF5EE). I have used "TButton" controls widely which doesn't have a  "Color" property.So, instead of changing the buttons to speed buttons, I have tried a different approach by introducing a parent form and inheriting all the other forms from this parent form. In the parent form, I have a class helper to change the color of buttons. Here is the code: (I am using Delphi 2007)

```
TButtonHelper=class helper for TButton
private
  procedure doChangeColor;
public
  procedure DrawChangeColor;
end;

TParentForm = class(TForm)
public
  procedure AfterConstruction; override;
end;
```

And in the implementation section, I have

```
    procedure TButtonHelper.doChangeColor;
    var
      SaveIndex: Integer;
      FCanvas:TCanvas;
      rect:TRect;
    begin
      if csDestroying in ComponentState then exit;
      FCanvas:=TCanvas.Create;

        SaveIndex := SaveDC(Self.Handle);
        FCanvas.Lock;
        try
          FCanvas.Handle := Handle;
          FCanvas.Font := Font;
          FCanvas.Brush := self.Brush;
          FCanvas.Brush.Color:=$00FCF5EE;
          FCanvas.FillRect(BoundsRect);//Omitting the code to draw the text
        finally
          FCanvas.Handle := 0;
          FCanvas.Unlock;
          RestoreDC(handle, SaveIndex);
          FCanvas.Free;
        end;
    end;


    procedure TButtonHelper.DrawChangeColor;
    begin
        doChangeColor;
        self.Repaint;
    end;

procedure TParentForm.AfterConstruction;
    var
     i : Integer;
     wc: TControl;
    begin
      inherited;
      for i := 0 to self.ControlCount - 1 do begin
         wc:=Controls[i];
         if wc is  TButton then
            TButton(wc).DrawChangeColor;
      end;
    end;
```

But this doesn't work. Although the doChangeColor method is executed, it is not changing the color of the button.Please let me know what I am missing here.

Thanking you all,

Pradeep

Comment: That code can't change the colour of the button. That's not how windows works. You need to override the `Paint` method for the buttons.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Since the button doesn't have a Paint method, I have created a child class TColorButton (similar to whosrdaddy's class below) and overridden the parent form's Readstate method as mentioned by you at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685863/replacing-a-component-class-in-delphi/4686920#4686920 and changing the color in form's Create/Paint methods. Butin both the cases, the TColorButton class did not receive the CN_DRAWITEM message. What could be the reason?

Comment: `TButton` does have a `Paint` method. Perhaps it uses the inherited one in `TWinControl`. Since it reflects the Windows `BUTTON` class, it doesn't implement the painting in Delphi. Instead it passes the message on to the Windows API.

Comment: Thank you David...but I couldn't find the Paint on TWincontrol or any other TButton ancestors. I could find a paint method on TCustomcontrol from which the TButton is not derived. Did you mean the WM_PAINT message handler?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's all handled in `WMPaint`. `Paint` is introduced in `TCustomControl`. ALl the same you are still in the same position that Windows is not going to paint a `TButton` in the color you want. It's going to use the prevailing theme. You need a different control.

Answer (score 5):

here's a class that adds color properties to the standard TButton:

```
unit u_class_colorbutton;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, StdCtrls, Buttons, ExtCtrls;

type
  TColorButton = class(TButton)
  private
    ShowBackColor  : Boolean;
    FCanvas        : TCanvas;
    IsFocused      : Boolean;
    FBackColor     : TColor;
    FForeColor     : TColor;
    FHoverColor    : TColor;
    procedure SetBackColor(const Value: TColor);
    procedure SetForeColor(const Value: TColor);
    procedure SetHoverColor(const Value: TColor);
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure WndProc(var Message : TMessage); override;

    procedure SetButtonStyle(Value: Boolean); override;
    procedure DrawButton(Rect: TRect; State: UINT);

    procedure CMEnabledChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_ENABLEDCHANGED;
    procedure CMFontChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_FONTCHANGED;
    procedure CNMeasureItem(var Message: TWMMeasureItem); message CN_MEASUREITEM;
    procedure CNDrawItem(var Message: TWMDrawItem); message CN_DRAWITEM;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property BackColor : TColor read FBackColor  write SetBackColor default clBtnFace;
    property ForeColor : TColor read FForeColor  write SetForeColor default clBtnText;
    property HoverColor: TColor read FHoverColor write SetHoverColor default clBtnFace;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

constructor TColorButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited Create(AOwner);
 ShowBackColor := True;
 FCanvas := TCanvas.Create;
 BackColor := clBtnFace;
 ForeColor := clBtnText;
 HoverColor := clBtnFace;
end;

destructor TColorButton.Destroy;
begin
 FreeAndNil(FCanvas);
 inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TColorButton.WndProc(var Message : TMessage);
begin
 if (Message.Msg = CM_MOUSELEAVE) then
  begin
   ShowBackColor := True;
   Invalidate;
  end;
 if (Message.Msg = CM_MOUSEENTER) then
  begin
   ShowBackColor := False;
   Invalidate;
  end;
 inherited;
end;

procedure TColorButton.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
 inherited CreateParams(Params);
  with Params do
    Style := Style or BS_OWNERDRAW;
end;

procedure TColorButton.SetButtonStyle(Value: Boolean);
begin
 if Value <> IsFocused then
  begin
   IsFocused := Value;
   Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TColorButton.CNMeasureItem(var Message: TWMMeasureItem);
begin
 with Message.MeasureItemStruct^ do
  begin
   itemWidth  := Width;
   itemHeight := Height;
  end;
end;

procedure TColorButton.CNDrawItem(var Message: TWMDrawItem);
var
  SaveIndex: Integer;
begin
 with Message.DrawItemStruct^ do
  begin
   SaveIndex := SaveDC(hDC);
   FCanvas.Lock;
   try
    FCanvas.Handle := hDC;
    FCanvas.Font   := Font;
    FCanvas.Brush  := Brush;
    DrawButton(rcItem, itemState);
   finally
    FCanvas.Handle := 0;
    FCanvas.Unlock;
    RestoreDC(hDC, SaveIndex);
   end;
 end;
 Message.Result := 1;
end;

procedure TColorButton.CMEnabledChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
 inherited;
 Invalidate;
end;

procedure TColorButton.CMFontChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
 inherited;
 Invalidate;
end;

procedure TColorButton.SetBackColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
 if FBackColor <> Value then
  begin
   FBackColor:= Value;
   Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TColorButton.SetForeColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
 if FForeColor <> Value then
  begin
   FForeColor:= Value;
   Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TColorButton.SetHoverColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
 if FHoverColor <> Value then
  begin
   FHoverColor:= Value;
   Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TColorButton.DrawButton(Rect: TRect; State: UINT);

var Flags, OldMode: Longint;
    IsDown, IsDefault, IsDisabled: Boolean;
    OldColor: TColor;
    OrgRect: TRect;
    NewCaption : string;

begin
 NewCaption := Caption;
 OrgRect := Rect;
 Flags := DFCS_BUTTONPUSH or DFCS_ADJUSTRECT;
 IsDown := State and ODS_SELECTED <> 0;
 IsDisabled := State and ODS_DISABLED <> 0;
 IsDefault := State and ODS_FOCUS <> 0;

 if IsDown then Flags := Flags or DFCS_PUSHED;
 if IsDisabled then Flags := Flags or DFCS_INACTIVE;

 if (IsFocused or IsDefault) then
  begin
   FCanvas.Pen.Color   := clWindowFrame;
   FCanvas.Pen.Width   := 1;
   FCanvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
   FCanvas.Rectangle(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom);
   InflateRect(Rect, - 1, - 1);
  end;

  if IsDown then
  begin
   FCanvas.Pen.Color   := clBtnShadow;
   FCanvas.Pen.Width   := 1;
   FCanvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;
   FCanvas.Rectangle(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom);
   InflateRect(Rect, - 1, - 1);
  end
 else
  begin
   DrawFrameControl(FCanvas.Handle, Rect, DFC_BUTTON, Flags);
  end;

  if IsDown then OffsetRect(Rect, 1, 1);

  OldColor := FCanvas.Brush.Color;
  if ShowBackColor then
   FCanvas.Brush.Color := BackColor
  else
   FCanvas.Brush.Color := HoverColor;
  FCanvas.FillRect(Rect);
  FCanvas.Brush.Color := OldColor;
  OldMode := SetBkMode(FCanvas.Handle, TRANSPARENT);
  FCanvas.Font.Color := ForeColor;
  if IsDisabled then
   DrawState(FCanvas.Handle, FCanvas.Brush.Handle, nil, Integer(NewCaption), 0,
             ((Rect.Right - Rect.Left) - FCanvas.TextWidth(NewCaption)) div 2,
             ((Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top) - FCanvas.TextHeight(NewCaption)) div 2,
             0, 0, DST_TEXT or DSS_DISABLED)
  else
   begin
    InflateRect(Rect, -4, -4);
    DrawText(FCanvas.Handle, PChar(NewCaption), - 1, Rect, DT_WORDBREAK or DT_CENTER);
   end;

  SetBkMode(FCanvas.Handle, OldMode);

 if (IsFocused and IsDefault) then
  begin
   Rect := OrgRect;
   InflateRect(Rect, - 4, - 4);
   FCanvas.Pen.Color   := clWindowFrame;
   FCanvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;
   DrawFocusRect(FCanvas.Handle, Rect);
  end;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Standard', [TColorButton]);
end;

initialization
  RegisterClass(TColorButton); // needed for persistence at runtime


end.
```

You can hack it into your application easily:
find/replace all TButton references to TColorButton 
inside your .pas and .dfm files.
You can set separate colors for background, font and hovering.

If you want add styling application wide, maybe it is better to create a GUI with a library that has native support like DevExpress, TMS, ...
Personally, I like DevExpress the most but that's a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Thank you whosrdaddy..But I have widely used the TButtons and changing the components in form will be my last step.

Comment: @user466744 You're not "changing the components" really. You're "inheriting" them and "overriding" their behavior. This is what you need to do, I don't understand why you refuse to accept this. The code has been written for you above.