# How to make custom BitBtn?

Tags: delphi

**How to make custom BitBtn with color property?**
I have found one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513628/delphi-changing-the-button-color-using-a-class-helper), but it is a `TButton` not `TBitBtn` so I have edited the code as follows :

```
unit ColorBitBtn;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, StdCtrls, Buttons, ExtCtrls;

type
  TColorBitBtn = class(TBitBtn)
  private
    ShowBackColor  : Boolean;
    FCanvas        : TCanvas;
    IsFocused      : Boolean;
    FBackColor     : TColor;
    FForeColor     : TColor;
    FHoverColor    : TColor;
    procedure SetBackColor(const Value: TColor);
    procedure SetForeColor(const Value: TColor);
    procedure SetHoverColor(const Value: TColor);
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure WndProc(var Message : TMessage); override;

    procedure SetBitBtnStyle(Value: Boolean);
    procedure DrawBitBtn(Rect: TRect; State: UINT);

    procedure CMEnabledChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_ENABLEDCHANGED;
    procedure CMFontChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_FONTCHANGED;
    procedure CNMeasureItem(var Message: TWMMeasureItem); message CN_MEASUREITEM;
    procedure CNDrawItem(var Message: TWMDrawItem); message CN_DRAWITEM;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property BackColor : TColor read FBackColor  write SetBackColor default clBtnFace;
    property ForeColor : TColor read FForeColor  write SetForeColor default clBtnText;
    property HoverColor: TColor read FHoverColor write SetHoverColor default clBtnFace;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

constructor TColorBitBtn.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited Create(AOwner);
 ShowBackColor := True;
 FCanvas := TCanvas.Create;
 BackColor := clBtnFace;
 ForeColor := clBtnText;
 HoverColor := clBtnFace;
end;

destructor TColorBitBtn.Destroy;
begin
 FreeAndNil(FCanvas);
 inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TColorBitBtn.WndProc(var Message : TMessage);
begin
 if (Message.Msg = CM_MOUSELEAVE) then
  begin
   ShowBackColor := True;
   Invalidate;
  end;
 if (Message.Msg = CM_MOUSEENTER) then
  begin
   ShowBackColor := False;
   Invalidate;
  end;
 inherited;
end;

procedure TColorBitBtn.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
 inherited CreateParams(Params);
  with Params do
    Style := Style or BS_OWNERDRAW;
end;

procedure TColorBitBtn.SetBitBtnStyle(Value: Boolean);
begin
 if Value <> IsFocused then
  begin
   IsFocused := Value;
   Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TColorBitBtn.CNMeasureItem(var Message: TWMMeasureItem);
begin
 with Message.MeasureItemStruct^ do
  begin
   itemWidth  := Width;
   itemHeight := Height;
  end;
end;

procedure TColorBitBtn.CNDrawItem(var Message: TWMDrawItem);
var
  SaveIndex: Integer;
begin
 with Message.DrawItemStruct^ do
  begin
   SaveIndex := SaveDC(hDC);
   FCanvas.Lock;
   try
    FCanvas.Handle := hDC;
    FCanvas.Font   := Font;
    FCanvas.Brush  := Brush;
    DrawBitBtn(rcItem, itemState);
   finally
    FCanvas.Handle := 0;
    FCanvas.Unlock;
    RestoreDC(hDC, SaveIndex);
   end;
 end;
 Message.Result := 1;
end;

procedure TColorBitBtn.CMEnabledChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
 inherited;
 Invalidate;
end;

procedure TColorBitBtn.CMFontChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
 inherited;
 Invalidate;
end;

procedure TColorBitBtn.SetBackColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
 if FBackColor <> Value then
  begin
   FBackColor:= Value;
   Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TColorBitBtn.SetForeColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
 if FForeColor <> Value then
  begin
   FForeColor:= Value;
   Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TColorBitBtn.SetHoverColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
 if FHoverColor <> Value then
  begin
   FHoverColor:= Value;
   Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TColorBitBtn.DrawBitBtn(Rect: TRect; State: UINT);

var Flags, OldMode: Longint;
    IsDown, IsDefault, IsDisabled: Boolean;
    OldColor: TColor;
    OrgRect: TRect;
    NewCaption : string;

begin
 NewCaption := Caption;
 OrgRect := Rect;
 Flags := DFCS_BUTTONPUSH or DFCS_ADJUSTRECT;
 IsDown := State and ODS_SELECTED <> 0;
 IsDisabled := State and ODS_DISABLED <> 0;
 IsDefault := State and ODS_FOCUS <> 0;

 if IsDown then Flags := Flags or DFCS_PUSHED;
 if IsDisabled then Flags := Flags or DFCS_INACTIVE;

 if (IsFocused or IsDefault) then
  begin
   FCanvas.Pen.Color   := clWindowFrame;
   FCanvas.Pen.Width   := 1;
   FCanvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
   FCanvas.Rectangle(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom);
   InflateRect(Rect, - 1, - 1);
  end;

  if IsDown then
  begin
   FCanvas.Pen.Color   := clBtnShadow;
   FCanvas.Pen.Width   := 1;
   FCanvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;
   FCanvas.Rectangle(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom);
   InflateRect(Rect, - 1, - 1);
  end
 else
  begin
   DrawFrameControl(FCanvas.Handle, Rect, DFC_BUTTON, Flags);
  end;

  if IsDown then OffsetRect(Rect, 1, 1);

  OldColor := FCanvas.Brush.Color;
  if ShowBackColor then
   FCanvas.Brush.Color := BackColor
  else
   FCanvas.Brush.Color := HoverColor;
  FCanvas.FillRect(Rect);
  FCanvas.Brush.Color := OldColor;
  OldMode := SetBkMode(FCanvas.Handle, TRANSPARENT);
  FCanvas.Font.Color := ForeColor;
  if IsDisabled then
   DrawState(FCanvas.Handle, FCanvas.Brush.Handle, nil, Integer(NewCaption), 0,
             ((Rect.Right - Rect.Left) - FCanvas.TextWidth(NewCaption)) div 2,
             ((Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top) - FCanvas.TextHeight(NewCaption)) div 2,
             0, 0, DST_TEXT or DSS_DISABLED)
  else
   begin
    InflateRect(Rect, -4, -4);
    DrawText(FCanvas.Handle, PChar(NewCaption), - 1, Rect, DT_WORDBREAK or DT_CENTER);
   end;

  SetBkMode(FCanvas.Handle, OldMode);

 if (IsFocused and IsDefault) then
  begin
   Rect := OrgRect;
   InflateRect(Rect, - 4, - 4);
   FCanvas.Pen.Color   := clWindowFrame;
   FCanvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;
   DrawFocusRect(FCanvas.Handle, Rect);
  end;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Standard', [TColorBitBtn]);
end;

initialization
  RegisterClass(TColorBitBtn); // needed for persistence at runtime


end.
```

After doing the same. it compiles perfectly without any error. But the Font.Color does not get changed on any event like `OnClick`, `OnMouseDown` etc and another problem is not look like `Button` or `BitBtn` after enabling Theme Manifest like the following picture

[image]

Here the first is Standard Button, Standard BitBtn followed by Custom BitBtn created by the above code after adding `Theme Manifest`.

Comment: After doing the same. it compiles perfectly without any error. But the `Font.Color` does not get changed on any event like `OnClick`, `OnMouseDown` etc and another problem is not look like `Button` or `BitBtn` after enabling `Theme Manifest`. I have just added the picture.

Comment: There is `Standard Button`, `Standard BitBtn` followed by `Custom BitBtn` created by the above code.

Comment: @user2612109 Okay, but that needs to be in the question, not the comments. Comments are not permanent, and can be deleted by moderators.

Comment: OK! I have just modified my question before your suggestion.

Comment: FYI the code from my answer was never meant to work with themes :). Basically the code is totally responsible how the button is painted. If you want round corners, you'll have to paint them...

Comment: @user2612109 Your first comment should be the info in your added edit. It should be rather a section of its own at the end of your question, separated with the word "EDIT" and followed by the info in your first comment.

Comment: What is your question? Please ask a direct specific question. How can you expect themed painting without calling the theme API? Perhaps you should use VCL styles.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't add color to the native drawing done by the OS. You need to draw the whole thing from scratch if you want it colored. Like David says, you should consider using VCL Styles, if your Delphi version supports it. Different versions of Windows will draw this button differently.

Comment: @Jerry - A `BitBtn` is an owner-drawn button control drawn in its entirety by the VCL. However I believe your comment still holds true leaving aside the minor nitpick.