# How to make transparent memos with VCL Themes?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm playing around with VCL Themes in Delphi 11. It's working great with already existent apps but the memos are not styled, they remain white as the image below shows.

What should i do to make the memo transparent ? Tried to set color to clNone and ParentColor true, but no luck.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `Bitmap Style Designer` from the `Tools` menu? Tip: make backup copies of the style files (.vsf) that you modify

Answer (score 0):

If you want your memo to have the same color as your form then I suggest you change its color from `clWindow` to `clBtnFace`.

Or you could change the color of `clWindow` color in `SysColors` section of your VCL style.

Note this will affect any control that is using `clWindow` color

Comment: It's already with clBtnFace, but still, when i activate a VCL theme, it changes the color. The workaround i've got so far is to manually change the color of the memo, to the same color the theme use on form. But it's a headache do it for each memo...

Comment: @delphirules Using an [interposer class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4685863/327083) is a usual hack in cases like this.  Ideally you would have subclassed the TMemo to begin with and then could have an easy way to globally modify all of them in your application, but this, at least, is a quick, albeit messy, way to get what you want in the meantime.