# Getting C++Builder derived vcl control class to work with form designer?

Tags: c++builder

I want to just do something simple, override `WM_COPY` of a `TEdit` control.

If I try to use the following, you can't change the type in the `.dfm` or it complains that it doesn't exist so you have to leave it `TEdit`.  But now when saving the `.h/.cpp` complains about it should be a `TEdit` when I want it to be `TMyEdit`.

In MyForm.h:

```
class TMyEdit : public TEdit
{
    private:
        virtual void __fastcall WndProc(TMessage &Message);
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TMyForm : public TForm
{
  // ...
  TMyEdit *m_MyEditCtl; // previously TEdit *m_MyEditCtl
  // ...
};
```

In the MyForm.cpp

```
// ...
void __fastcall TMyEdit::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    if (Message.Msg == WM_COPY) {
      // I'll handle it ....
    }
    else {
        __super::WndProc(Message);
    }
}
// ...
```

What is the correct way to do this in C++Builder so it works in the form and C++ source files?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design-time controls *must* be installed in the IDE.  So, if you want to use your custom `TMyEdit` at design-time, you will have to move it into a separate `.BPL` package, and then you can install that package into the IDE and have it register your class.  Only then will you be able to use your class with the Form Designer.

Read Embarcadero's documentation for more details about writing custom components:

[Introduction to component creation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Introduction_to_component_creation_Index)

---

**UPDATE**:

However, that being said, there is an alternative (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4685907/65863)), which will allow you to use the standard `TEdit` at design-time, and use `TMyEdit` at runtime, no `.BPL` needed:

```
class TMyEdit : public TEdit
{
    // ...
};

class TMyForm : public TForm
{
__published:
    // ...
    TEdit *m_MyEditCtl;
    // ...
protected:
    virtual void __fastcall ReadState(TReader *Reader);
    // ...
private:
    void __fastcall FindComponentClass(TReader *Reader, const String ClassName, TComponentClass &ComponentClass);
    // ...
};

void __fastcall TMyForm::ReadState(TReader *Reader)
{
    Reader->OnFindComponentClass = &FindComponentClass;
    TForm::ReadState(Reader);
}

void __fastcall TMyForm::FindComponentClass(TReader *Reader, const String ClassName, TComponentClass &ComponentClass)
{
    if (ComponentClass == __classid(TEdit))
        ComponentClass = __classid(TMyEdit);
}
```